# Get data from datetime element

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to extract the date from `datetime` element below.

```
<time datetime="2015-12-18T12:38" pubdate> 18 december 12:38</time>
```

How could I do that, i.e. get `2015-12-18T12:38`?

I know that I can extract text `"18 december 12:38"`. But it is now what I want.

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the attribute value of that element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("time")[0].getAttribute("datetime");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jquery `.attr()` - http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$('time').attr('datetime')
```

Comment: The OP has not asked for nor indicated the use of any library, so suggesting an answer that requires one isn't a good idea.

Comment: @RobG i suggested first what came to my mind, as you can see my answer is not marked as resolving one.

Comment: Then it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @RobG what is wrong with post ? isn't it answer for some variation of such question ? there is possibility that OP forgot to mention that he uses jquery and this answer can help him or he want to use jquery but don't know that it possible with jquery or some other user who came here with same question and uses jquery ...